# Whats the joint PDF of Z=XY given the a joint pdf f(x,y)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, transformation

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with joint pdf:
>
> $$f(x,y)=x + y \quad \text{if } x \ge 0, y \le 1$$
>
> Let $Z=XY$. Calculate the pdf of $Z$.

I'm a bit confused about solving this problem, I'm trying to get to the pdf by calculating the cdf to derive it afterwards, so I know that the cdf of $Z$ would be something like this:

$$F(XY \le z) = \iint(x+y) \,dydx.$$

But I'm not so sure how to would the limits of the definite would be...Im guessing it's:

$$F(XY \le z)= \int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{z/x}(x+y) \,dy dx.$$

But this integral's result is divergent, so I know something is wrong but I'm a bit lost there. Is there a better approach on solving it? Any thoughts?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: The problem doesn't mention if X and Y are continuous, I'm also assuming that.

Comment: your pdf is negative for $y<-x$, how is that possible?

Comment: @Exodd how so? Do you think there's an error in the problem?

Comment: That is not a proper pdf so i believe the Intended constraint was $y\ge 1$

Comment: Calculate the integral  for  $x \in [0, 10]$ and $ y \in [-100, 1]$ you will get a -44945 a pdf is the functional form of a positive measure so it cannot evaluate to a negative in any region of R2

Comment: @NoeVidales I see, but isn't it valid to think that if $ x≥0$ and $y≤1$ then $the product of both XY would be inside the (0,1) interval?

Comment: @JoseLuisPacheco What happens when x=1000,  and y=1 does it lie in (0,1). Under your constraints then the range of $XY$ is any number in $\mathcal{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So indeed, if $Z = XY$, let $\mathbb{I}(A)$ denote the indicator of the event $A$ (i.e. $\mathbb{I}(A)=1$ if $A$ is true and is $0$ otherwise). You have
$$
\begin{split}
F_Z(z)
 &= \mathbb{P}[Z \le z] \\
 &= \mathbb{P}[XY \le z] \\
 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty
        \mathbb{I}(xy \le z) f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ dxdy \\
 &= \int_{x=-\infty}^{x=0}
    \int_{y=z/x}^{y=\infty} f(x,y) dy dx
  + \int_{x=0}^{x=\infty}
    \int_{y=-\infty}^{y=z/x} f(x,y) dy dx
\end{split}
$$

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I missed that you gave the definition for $f(x,y) = x+y$ for $x \ge 0$ and $y \le 1$. I don't understand how this is a valid pdf -- you must have
$$
1 = \int_{x=0}^{x=\infty} \int_{y = -\infty}^{y=1} (x+y)dxdy
$$
but the RHS integral diverges...

**UPDATE 2**

I think the intent is to have $f(x,y)=x+y$ for $0 \le x,y \le 1$, which means $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$. Indeed,
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (x+y)dxdy
 &= \int_0^1 \left[y + \left(\int_0^1 x dx\right) \right]dy\\
 &= \int_0^1 \left[y + \frac12 \right]dy \\
 &= \int_0^1 y dy + \frac12 \\
 &= \frac12 + \frac12 \\
 &= 1.
\end{split}
$$
Then, 
$$
\begin{split}
F_Z(z)
 &= \int_{x=0}^{x=1}
    \int_{y=0}^{y=\min\{z/x,1\}} (x+y) dy dx
\end{split}
$$
Can you now finish?

Comment: What do you mean by  $\mathbb{I}(xy \le z)$? Can you please elaborate? thanks!

Comment: @JoseLuisPacheco added clarification

Comment: I understand better now, but what about  x and y being $x≥0,y≤1$ ? Doesn't it imply that P(XY≤z) would be calculated within the range that goes from 0 to 1 ?

Comment: @JoseLuisPacheco please see the update

Comment: that's right! That's what I also don't get :(

Comment: @JoseLuisPacheco figured it out, i think; please see update #2

Comment: Ok! Let me see if I get it. So if it is equal to 1 (within the interval $[0,1]$ ) it is, by definition, a valid CDF. Then you are defining the CDF properly in terms of  $z$, but why are you considering the minimum function in the boundaries? In that case the minimum wouldn't be z/x?

Comment: @JoseLuisPacheco $z/x$ does not have to be bigger or smaller than one. For example, if $z = 0.5,x=0.4$ then $z/x>1$...

Comment: I'm going to check now how to evaluate that integral with min function as the upper boundary to get to the final pdf! However I'm accepting your response as an answer to this question, thanks! :)